# how to auto navigate ngu carousel dots

Tags: angular, npm

using Ngu carousel https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngu/carousel.
I am trying auto navigate dote on slide change like this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yqgpya?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts.
in this demo use bootstrap carousel but I am using ngu carousel.

Thanks in advance.